# Woocommerce product category page title

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi great peoples of stackoverflow!

I have a wordpress project which is utilises woocommerce plugin to list out the products that we have on the website. The problem is, in the product categories page, the page title is not the product category, it comes out as the 1st product in the product category. e.g. "Item A" is a product under "Category" category, the page title in "Category" category page,  appeared as "Item A | Site Name" it should be "Category | Site Name". Is there any way that we can fix this?

We also have Yoast SEO plugin activated.

Comment: Deactivate the Yoast Plugin and confirm if that's causing it. Also, what theme are you using?

Comment: I'm using theretailer theme.

Comment: Do you still get the issue if the Yoast plugin is deactivated? You need to first establish if it's being caused by the plugin or the theme.

Comment: Is the meta settings for the yoast plugin going to disappear if I deactivate it?

Comment: A quick look at the plugin files suggests that it doesn't remove any data when deactivating, so you should be ok. To be on the safe side you could do a backup of your database first.